# Qt minimizing Dialog minimize Parent Window

Tags: qt, dialog, window

In my application I have a parent window and over it a child dialog, when I minimize my child dialog parent window also get minimized,  how can I avoid it. The child dialog is sub-classed from `QDialog`

And the child dialog pop-up is executed in this way,

```
    ChildDilago PopUp;
    PopUp.setModal(false);
    Qt::WindowFlags flags = Qt::Window | Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint
                                | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint
                                | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint;
    PopUp.setWindowFlags(flags);
    PopUp.setUI(data);
    PopUp.exec();
```

What can be the issue here?, any help will be appreciated...

Thanks
Haris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by replacing

```
 PopUp.exec();
```

with

```
PopUp.show();
```